# Keep outdated Centos 5.6 (Final) - Install latest Samba

Tags: centos, samba

Without having to update the CentOs, how would you go about updating to the latest samba?

Would i have to download and compile it on the machine, or would their be a repository that handles older linux distros.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://vault.centos.org/5.6/) is the repo with packages for 5.6 But I would recommend you to upgrade at least to Centos 5.11

Comment: I appreciate the idea.  It appears i have successfully updated to 5.11 , and that got me Samba 3.6 which was a newer version than i had.

Is there a way to install a version of Samba that is beyond what is available in the Repo being the repo is no longer updated.